# Populating dictionary from spreadsheet

Tags: python

My goal is to convert the list into a dictionary with items `{2000:5593976709, ..., 2020:0}` where keys are the years and values are the sum of the years. The list looks like this (where each value is preceded with the corresponding year):

```py
year mileage = [ 2000, 366607410, 2000, 366139276, 2000, 453096388, 
    2000, 473751011, 2000, 481725263, 2000, 517102460, ..., 2020, 0 ]
```

Using `dict(year_mileage)` doesn't work as it gives the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#112>", line 1, in <module>
    dict(year_mileage)
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

Comment: Can you please give some output snippet of `row` variable

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No one can help you fully, since you didn't give enough data for us to help. For example: we don't know how the spreadsheet looks like. It would be beneficial if you read the MRE, as stated before.

Answer (score -1):

In python, it is very easy to populate a dictionary. All you need is to have a variable set to a dictionary type and things will work like magic. For example:

```py
# declare a variable which is a dictionary
dict = {}

# add a non-existant key and value to the dictionary
dict[2000] = 5593967709
```

This way, all you have left to do is get the year and corresponding sum from your spreadsheet, and add them to a dictionary like I've mentioned.

Now, considering you want to add the sums of all the values in the list in the year's key, you can do the following:

```py
dict = {}

# i equals 0 at the beginning, and is added 2 every iteration of the loop, 
# until it's larger than the list's length
for i in range(0, len(year_mileage), 2):
    # get(key, [default]) method returns the value of the key given, 
    # otherwise returns the default value given
    dict[key] = dict.get(i, 0) + year_mileage[i + 1]
```

Comment: Please read the posting more carefully: OP wants to sum values for the year, that data taken from rows of the spreadsheet.  Granted, it's not described well.

Comment: @Prune, as far as I've understood, he doesn't know how to populate a dictionary, thus that is the information I've given him. I can't help with getting the data from the spreadsheet since he didn't add a reference as to how it looks like...